# Recursion: Displaying numbers from a to b, and showing their sum

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to understand, where is the sum comes from? I know what recursion is, but I can't figure out how `int i` gets the sum. I have read about the stack... but I still don't understand. Please help :)
here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = RecursiveMethod(1,3);
    //Console.ReadLine();
}

static int RecursiveMethod(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    if (a == b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else 
    {
        return a + RecursiveMethod(a + 1, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement inside your RecursiveMethod sets `i` that is why the type of your method is `int`, it returns an integer, so by saying `int i = RecursiveMethod(1, 3)` it is saying set `i` to the value returned from `RecursiveMethod`. Try changing i to a different type like string or double and you will get a compiler error.

Comment: to understand recursion, first see recursion

Comment: @realdoctor Maybe I didn't explain what you were asking, the recursive method will continue execution until the condition a == b is reached, at that point it will return to Main and set  i to the value from your recursive method, in the else portion of the recursive method it is saying to return a's current value plus the value returned by another iteration(call to recursive method) so on the first pass it would be 1 + the return of RecursiveMethod(2, 3) etc. Recursive calls to a function can be done with a while loop as well.

Comment: @realdoctor Write on paper values of all variables in each layer of recursion. Then, write a simple for loop that does the same thing as recursion. You'll see recursion is very similar to simple loop, it's just isn't so easy to see what's going on and in most cases, it's much more easier to use recursion instead of a for loop.

Comment: You have a bug in your recursive function.  If `a` is ever greater than `b`, you will have infinite recursion, and likely get a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go step by step what's happening when you call `RecursiveMethod(1,3);`

1. Code enters the else branch because `a` is not equal to `b`
2. Call `RecursiveMethod(2,3)`
3. Code enters the else branch again because a is not equal to b
4. Call `RecursiveMethod(3,3)`
5. The if condition is met and we hit our first return which returns `3`
6. Now we are in the else branch of step 2 because `RecursiveMethod(3,3)` returned. The step 2 was like this: `return 2 + RecursiveMethod(3,3)` so it becomes: `2 + 3` and it returns `5`
7. Now we come to the last return, we are in Step 1, no more inner returns left. Step 2 returned `5` so the `return 1 + 5` = `6`

With each recursive call you go one level deeper. You must hit return at some point otherwise the method will keep getting called and eventually you will get a `StackOverFlowException`. This is because each method has a stack that keeps the parameters, local variables and other stuff, when you keep calling the function all these values will be pushed to the stack over and over again, for each call and eventually you will run out of stack space.

The number of return statements you hit should be equal to the number of recursive calls you make. Last return which returns to the caller is not included. In the above function we made two recursive calls and we hit 2 returns and the final one which returned to `Main`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra text portions to your answer, that was what I was trying to show from my answer with the while loop but I took it down as it seemed like people didn't understand where I was going with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `i` value comes from the result of the recursion itself.
First time the `RecursiveMethod` is invoked, it will finish in two different ways:

1) returning `a` as result if `a == b`
2) returning the result of the (recursive) invocation of the method `RecursiveMethod`

In your example, where the method is invoked with `(1,3)`, it will land in the second case and therefor will require another iteration of the method, invoked recursively.

The second iteration will perform same checks, but this time it will not have `(1,3)` as values, but `(2,3)` instead.

Result will be a final third iteration where the result will be `3` cause the `(3,3)` params will satisfy the condition `a == b`.

At the end, the result will be `a (as 1) + a (as 2) + 3 (as recursion result) = 1+2+3 = 6`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: [Watch and QuickWatch Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) to see how you can step through the code in the debugger and see how the values change.

The key to recursive methods is that they always have some condition in which they return an actual value (without calling themselves). In your case, it's when `a == b`. The recursive part is when it increments `a` and then calls itself again. So the first call to the method waits for the second call to return, which waits for the third call to return. At the third call, we've met our condition `a == b`, so a value is returned and then the stack "unwinds".

Perhaps this diagram illustrating the flow through the stack (sort of) will help. I've left out the main logic (and showing each variable value at each step) to avoid confusion, and only included the `return` portion of the call:

```
i = RecursiveMethod(1, 3);
    ┗► return 1 + RecursiveMethod(2, 3);
                  ┗► return 2 + RecursiveMethod(3, 3);
                                ┗► return 3;
                     return 2 + 3 ◄┛
       return 1 + 5 ◄┛
i = 6 ◄┛
```

Note that there's a fatal flaw in this method, which is that it assumes that `a` is less than or equal to `b`. Try calling the method with `a = 3` and `b = 1`, and it will recursively call itself until the stack overflows because incrementing `a` will never meet the exit condition `a == b`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to visualize the process by showing the recursion as nested calls in pseudo code:

```
static int RecursiveMethod(int a(=1), int b(=3))
{
    if (a == b) // FALSE
    {
        return a; // NOT EXECUTED
    }
    else 
    {
        return a(=1)                                                 // ==> RETURNS 1 + 5 = 6
            + RecursiveMethod(int a+1(=2), int b(=3))                                   ^
              {                                                                         |
                  if (a == b) // FALSE                                                  |
                  {                                                                     |
                      return a; // NOT EXECUTED                                         |
                  }                                                                     |
                  else                                                                  |
                  {                                                                     |
                      return a(=2)                               // ==> RETURNS 2 + 3 = 5
                          + RecursiveMethod(int a+1(=3), int b(=3))                 ^
                            {                                                       |
                                if (a == b) // TRUE                                 |
                                {                                                   |
                                    return a;                        // ==> RETURNS 3
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    return a + RecursiveMethod(a + 1, b); // NOT EXECUTED
                                }
                            }                                           
                  }
              }                                           
    }
}
```

First the recursive calls enter top down until the recursion stops because `a == b`, then the results bubble up